# Can a 22 gauge 10 conductor multi-core wire be used in a home Ethernet implementation? What will be the data rate/range on this setup?

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

The whole wire is *un*-shielded, like this one.

[image]

These 10 wires are insulated individually and are not twisted.

I read somewhere that it's a standard communication cable.

Comment: "Standard communication cable" probably meant for phones, not for data on twisted pairs. High frequence transmission works very different from low frequency transmission. I heard from people getting 10 MBit/s with weird setups, if that is fast enough for you in times of Gigabit-Ethernet ...

Comment: No.  You REALLY want them twisted, it's not going to do what you think it will do.

Comment: One thing not mentioned is that twisted pair cables are also impedance matched. Meaning that resistance over distance will be as close as possible across all wires. That is very important quality in twisted pair Ethernet cables that’s not present in other types of “communication cables”.

Comment: It also really depends (apart from the frequency/data rate) on the distance, or, rather, the two are inversely correlated.

Comment: Do you have any reason at all to expect that this would work?  If so, what is it?

Comment: @Alexey Kamenskiy: What do you mean by *"resistance over distance"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen that maybe is not the best way to express what I meant. Not a native speaker here. It suppose to mean that on a common communication cable the longer the distance the more resistance of the individual wires will deviate due to varying lengths AND diameters. In specialized twisted pair cables this effect while still present is not as strong. And hence different categories of twisted pair cables (Cat5, Cat6 etc) where the tolerances are tighter but also the recommended wire length is shorter. There are other things at play as well of course.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't run proper cable?   Cat6 is around 50c a metre.

Comment: You may be confused having seen multi-strand UTP ethernet-rated cabling.  I remember getting an entire rack relocated in a previous job, and there were about 180 jacks.  The cablers used 30 runs of 25 pair cat5  wires to connect a Concatenation Point to the new rack so six jacks connected through each 25 pair cable.  At the time, 30 runs was cheaper than 180 runs of cat5 cable, though that's probably changed now.   Point is, this was rated as cat5 UTP cabling, not some crusty phone wiring.

Comment: If you make the cable really short it will work, otherwise not.

Comment: If you really want to get something like this to work, I suggest using power line communication devices.  The signal processing on that stuff is insane and can recover signals after pretty much anything you throw at it.  Unfortunately, you'd have to modify the circuit board to cut the power feed from the signal feed.  We did it for a non-traditional high-noise network and it worked great.

Answer (score 37):

That will work very badly, if at all.

I actually tried this many years ago by using 4-wire non-shielded and non-twisted cable (also 22 AWG) instead of a regular CAT5.
In theory, you only need 4 wires for 10/100 Mb/s so I had a chance it would work.

Well, it did, sort of, but not good enough to be usable.

I was able to get signal across over about 10 meters maximum, but the network cards wouldn't auto-negotiate AT ALL.
I had to manually set the interfaces on both ends to 10 Mb/s and half-duplex. Even then I lost more than 60% of the network packets to transmission errors.
With a lot of luck and prayer, I was able to get a very unreliable 3 to 4 Mb/s over the cable.

Don't even bother trying. I can promise you a lot of wasted effort and frustration if you do.

Comment: I once had some cat5 that I got from a friend that had been terminated incorrectly (all 8 pins went through to the corresponding pin on the other end, but they weren't paired properly) and had the same result. It was usable at 10-HD, but unusable at anything higher, and auto-negotiation would try to pick 100-FD. In the end of course I cut off the connectors and re-terminated it properly.

Comment: The twists are absolutely required. They have a specification and are done to a standard. The amount of data flowing through a 100Mb, nevermind 1000Mb, requires them.
Forget having fully untwisted or even incorrectly paired wires, if you terminate the RJ45 with too much wire untwisted, it'll still mess up the data transmission, albeit to a lesser degree.

Comment: Even Cat-3 TP that works well at 10 Mb/s will fail to run 100 Mb/s. Twisted-pair for data comms is remarkably highly engineered.

Comment: Cables like these are essentially telephone cables, and if you want to get a feeling how horrendously bad those cables are for data transfer, you need only look at the insane complexity of the various higher-rate DSL standards. Even 10GbE Ethernet over Cat 7 is relatively simple, but extracting just 50 Mbps out of a telephone cable requires some serious amount of DSP processing, maths, and engineering. They would *love* to make those modems cheaper if they could, it's not like they overcomplicate this stuff for the fun of it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's actually a valid answer to OP's problem. They could likely run VDSL over that cabling (perhaps even multiple aggregated VDSL links) if they _really_ wanted to. Of course, the necessary hardware would be orders of magnitude more expensive than new TP cabling or a point-to-point wireless link.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It's noteworthy that, if we can believe [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_1_cable), even the most basic Level 1 cable, voice-grade (only), is twisted pair.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica CAT1 was never an official standard and there are dozens of different cables all called CAT1. Some are twisted, others not, shielded versions exist as well. None of those are suited for regular Ethernet. Even if they are twisted the twist-ratio will not be correct and that is just as bad as no twist at all. If it isn't correct (in combination with the impedance)  it just acts as a filter dampening the frequencies you need for Ethernet operation.

Comment: `In theory, you only need 4 wires for 10/100 Mb/s`  This is also true *in practice*, so there's not really anything added by saying "in theory".  It's a 4-wire protocol.  Period.

Comment: I've tried what OP's suggesting once out of desperation and can confirm that the resulting signal will be garbage. I ultimately got mine to work, but only at 10Mbps and when the total length of the non-twisted pair wire was around the length of my thumb (just enough to pass through the wall of an enclosure that already had wiring run through it).  Doing this over any appreciable distance will be a nightmare.

Comment: @J... In hindsight I formulated that backwards :-) I obviously meant to say "you only need 4 wires, so in theory I had a chance it would work".

Answer (score 5):

This will not work well. Ethernet cable has twisted pairs to reduce the effect of capacitance and electromagnetic fields between the wires. This serves to increase speed in the cable. The twist also provides for (fairly) constant impedance along the cable. Without the twist, impedance would be an issue and so the signals would not terminate correctly.

Standard cable, non-twisted pairs may work but will be slower.

You should use the cable prescribed for Ethernet and not a substitute.

Here is a useful article to help you.

[https://www.truecable.com/blogs/cable-academy/why-are-wires-twisted-inside-an-ethernet-cable#:~:text=Ethernet%20cable%20is%20very%20low,in%20their%20individual%20electromagnetic%20fields](https://www.truecable.com/blogs/cable-academy/why-are-wires-twisted-inside-an-ethernet-cable#:%7E:text=Ethernet%20cable%20is%20very%20low,in%20their%20individual%20electromagnetic%20fields).

Comment: You could also say something about impedance matching (signal interference may or may not be the only problem). E.g., is there a *required* impedance (with some tolerance) for the cable (or signal lines) or not?

Comment: I amended my post as you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There are two electrical things that you must consider.

- magnetically coupled
- differential signals

I break the ethernet standard all of the time due to the nature of my work.  I often use capacitive coupling instead of magnetics due to magnetic sensors.

The ability for a different wire to work will be a function of distance.  I need copper (due to resistance and something called "skin effect") for long distances, as the ethernet specs are written around these.  The copper clad aluminum wires are fine for short distances, and cheap, which is why they are used.

Regarding the "twisted" nature of the wires, this is the most important as the [differential signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling) cancels noise from the environment.  The ethernet signal is an analog signal (digital is a special case of analog), which is why the differential signal is important.

I believe that you could get several meters with a non-twisted wires.  I use straight leads across the PCB all of the time, but I've designed for this.

You would be better off to purchase a cable with 2 twisted pairs, but I'm confident that you could just use 22awg wire as long as the other conductors are DC.